# Get NFT Token Price

Tags: javascript, nft, ethers.js, erc-721, opensea

I'm using JavaScript, and trying to obtain an individual token price from a platform like OpenSea, without using the OpenSea API.

Popular SDKs like Alchemy and Moralis can return the floor price, or historical prices, but can't return the current price of an individual token.

Appreciate any suggestions that can help point me in the right direction. Thanks for your help.